# WPF binding command to Datacontext inside Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, icommand

I am just getting started with WPF and MVVM and managed to bind my **Datagrid** to the list **ProductList** of my DataContext ViewModel Class. However, I am now trying to **bind the buttons** inside my DataGrid to some Commands of my DataContext Class.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No MAT" Binding="{Binding MATProductNumber}" Width="0.1*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Format" Binding="{Binding tblFormat.FormatName}" Width="0.1*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom produit" Binding="{Binding tblProduct.ProductName}" Width="0.1*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productGradeHeader" Header="Grade" Binding="{Binding tblGrade.GradeName}" Width="0.1*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width=".1*"           
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate> 
                     <DataTemplate>
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <Button x:Name="leftArrowSearchButton" Command="{Binding PreviousPageCommand}" CommandParameter="1">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowLeftThick" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                          </Button>
                          <Button x:Name="rightArrowSearchButton" Command="{Binding NextPageCommand}" CommandParameter="1">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowRightThick" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                          </Button>
                       </StackPanel>
                     </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This line right here is supposed to Bind to **PreviousPageCommand** in my Data context

```
<Button x:Name="leftArrowSearchButton" Command="{Binding PreviousPageCommand}" CommandParameter="1"  ToolTip="Voir la page précédente" Height="24" Width="53" Margin="0,0,20,0">
```

I have debugged and found out that it's not even calling the function. Therefore, I am almost certain that there is a problem with the binding.

It seems like my button is trying to Bind to an element of ProductsList. Is there a way of going back one level up? I have already tried binding my buttons to DataContext.PreviousPageCommand

Thanks in Advance!

Edit 1: Here is the code in the Backend as requested

```
 public ObservableCollection<tblMATProduct> ProductsList { get; set; }

 private void NextPageScrollCommand(string number)
 {
     Page++;
     navigate(Page, Size);
 }

 public void navigate(int page, int size)
 {
     var result = new ObservableCollection<tblMATProduct>(db.tblMATProduct.Include(s => s.tblGrade).Include(s => s.tblProduct).Include(s => s.tblFormat).OrderBy(s => s.MATProductID).Skip(page * size).Take(size).ToList());
     ProductsList = result;
 }
```

ProductsList is updating, I can see it in the debugger. It's only the UI that's not updating.

**Edit 2:** It's working fine now! Just added this line to my ProductsList setter:

```
set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _products, value);
        }
```

Comment: You can bind Source = mydatagrid.DataContext Path = PreviousPageCommand, basically binding to myDataGrid DataContext which is your ViewModel

Comment: It says it can't read myDataGrid even though I have set it as x:Name of my Datagrid, how else could I refer to it?

Comment: Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.PreviousPageCommand}"

Comment: Previous page seems a bit of an odd command to be associated with a record in a datagrid. Previous page for the specific product? Anyhow. You'll also need to bind the selecteditem of your datagrid so the viewmodel knows which row the button was in when the user clicks. Or bind the datacontext of the button to the commandparameter.

Comment: Wow, now it's working. Can't thank you enough! If you want to post it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in my comment you need to bind to (ViewModel) `Parent/Ancestor.DataContext`

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.PreviousPageCommand}"
```

You'll also need to bind the `SelectedItem` of your `DataGrid` so the ViewModel knows which row the button was in when the user clicks. Or bind the `DataContext` of the button to the `CommandParameter`. like **@Andy** mentioned in the comment

Comment: Thanks for your help, the command is working. The only problem now is that although it's binding well and updating in the back-end, the UI is not updating even when ProductsList (binded to the DataGrid) is updated after executing the command.

Comment: can you share the code that updates the Products? Is the ProductsList of type ObservableCollection?

Comment: Just found the solution, thanks a lot for you help it's really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can do as follow:

```
{Binding DataContext.PreviousPageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}
```

But the binding will be update only when DataGrid.DataContext'll change, and not when DataContext.PreviousPageCommand'll change.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the command is working. The only problem now is that although it's binding well and updating in the back-end, the UI is not updating even when ProductsList (binded to the DataGrid) is updated after executing the command.

Comment: Do you mean add or remove elements to the List? Or change the List with new instance?
The binding will update only in second case. You've to use [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated my solution. I used the INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the view whenever a change happened.